# Add a node to the explorer tree in the netbeans platform without selection

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

I check some netbeans platform tutorials about how to configure some TopComponents components for acting as an ExplorerManager.Provider, and then get the selected objects of the tree with the LookupListener. That's ok. What I don't see is how to add some child nodes to the explorer tree directly to the root, it doesn't matter which node is selected or if the explorer component has the focus. Let's say like the New/Project action. Can some one give me some examples?

```
@ActionID(
        category = "File",
        id = "com.dataflowdesginer.core.generic.actions.NewProject"
)
@ActionRegistration(
        displayName = "#CTL_NewProject"
)
@ActionReference(path = "Menu/File/New", position = 1300)
@Messages("CTL_NewProject=Project")
public final class NewProject implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //get the tree here and add a new Project object to the root
    }

}
```